# css gradient background on <body> that stretches to 100% width and height

Tags: css, gradient

So I'd like to have a gradient that fills 100% of the background of a webpage. For browsers that can't handle it, a solid color is fine.

here is my current css:

```
html {
height: 100%;
}
body {
height: 100%;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background: #afb1b4; /* Old browsers */
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #afb1b4 0%, #696a6d 100%) no-repeat; /* FF3.6+ */
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#afb1b4), color-stop(100%,#696a6d)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #afb1b4 0%,#696a6d 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #afb1b4 0%,#696a6d 100%); /* Opera11.10+ */
background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #afb1b4 0%,#696a6d 100%); /* IE10+ */
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#AFB1B4', endColorstr='#696A6D',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */
background: linear-gradient(top, #afb1b4 0%,#696a6d 100%); /* W3C */
}
```

It seemed to work out while the page had little content, but as I've filled out the page with more content, navigation, etcetera, there is now some white at the bottom. maybe 100px or so. Am I doing this wrong? Do I need to be offsetting some padding somewhere?

Comment: looks like you got this from here: http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/

Comment: @Jason, I did, it's pretty thoroughly cross-browser, which I like. However, I've yet to test non-FF browsers. That bit comes soon.

Comment: i use it a lot. it is very cross-browser and works really well.

Comment: If you don't care about backwards compatability (fallback to flat color), why not get rid of 6 lines of code and use an SVG gradient via `background-image: url()`? It works in IE9+, FF4, Webkit since forever, and Opera 10.

Comment: Because an extra few lines of code gets me a whole lot of the older browsers. I wont worry about ancient browsers, but if I can have it work in the majority of browsers, that's definitely my preference.

Comment: @Unfortunately, but you can get the same compatability AND not have different sytle property rules (since webkit differs form everyone else, gradient filter is proprietary, etc) in one line with one file.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Get rid of your `height: 100%` declarations. It seems like setting the height to 100% just sets it to 100% of the viewport, not actually 100% of the page itself.

Comment: Thanks, this did it! The code below, even with the height: 100% thrown in there, worked as well. Removing the height does seem like the right way to do it, though.

Comment: @Jason : What happened to the fiddle?

Answer (score 4):

Here's an expansion of my comment to use SVG instead of vendor prefix and proprietary extensions. This reduces the size of the CSS and, with the employment of some ingenius tactics, can allow you to use a single SVG file as a sprite pack for gradients (reducing the total number of HTTP requests).

First create your SVG file and gradient (per your question specs):

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="no"?>
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd">
<svg width="1" height="500" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <g>
        <defs>
            <linearGradient id="ui-bg-grad" x1="0%" x2="0%" y1="0%" y2="100%">
                <stop offset="0%" stop-color="#afb1b4" />
                <stop offset="100%" stop-color="#696a6d" />
            </linearGradient>
        </defs>
        <rect fill="url(#ui-bg-grad)" x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="500"/>
    </g>
</svg>
```

Next, here's your new declaration:

```
html {
    height: 100%;
}
body {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-color: #afb1b4; /* Old browsers: anything not listed below */
    background-image: url("grad.svg"); /** Browsers that support SVG: IE9+, FF4+, Safari 4+(maybe 5), Opera 10+
}
```

Now, if you want to support older browsers with png image, you can with one little change. Since any property that uses `url()` does not support hinting (like `@font-face`'s `src` property), you have to alter the rule a little.

```
html {
    height: 100%;
}
body {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-color: #afb1b4; /* Image fails to load, or FF3.5 */
    background-image: url("grad.png"); /* Old browsers: anything not listed below or above */
}

body:not(foo) { /* most browsers that support :not() support SVG in url(), except FF3.5 */
    background-image: url("grad.svg"); /* Browsers that support SVG: IE9+, FF4+, Safari 4+(maybe 5), Opera 10+ */
}
```

If you want to get stupid crazy, you could base64encode the SVG file so that you don't have to download another file from the server then add it as a class to be reused (prevent repasting the base64 in multiple place).

```
.svg-sprite:not(foo)
{
    background-size: 100% 100%;
    background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml;base64,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");
}

html {
    height: 100%;
}

body {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-color: #afb1b4; /* Image fails to load, or FF3.5 */
    background-image: url("grad.png"); /* Old browsers: anything not listed below or above */
}
```

Then update your `body` tag to include the `.svg-sprite` class.

Comment: I'd vote this up if I had 15 reputation. Fantastic, thorough answer. Much appreciated!

Comment: @Unfortunately, np. I just have an issue with the fact that a perfectly portable, and stable, spec is not seeing as much influence as css gradients (which is still very much in dev).

Answer (score 1):

I also found that adding 'fixed' to the end seemed to do the trick:

```
body {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background: #afb1b4; /* Old browsers */
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #afb1b4 0%, #696a6d 100%) fixed no-repeat; /* FF3.6+ */
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#afb1b4), color-stop(100%,#696a6d)) fixed; /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #afb1b4 0%,#696a6d 100%) fixed; /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #afb1b4 0%,#696a6d 100%) fixed; /* Opera11.10+ */
background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #afb1b4 0%,#696a6d 100%) fixed; /* IE10+ */
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#AFB1B4', endColorstr='#696A6D',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */
background: linear-gradient(top, #afb1b4 0%,#696a6d 100%) fixed; /* W3C */
}
```

Comment: Note that this will drastically reduce performance on even the newer browsers!

Comment: Good to know! Is an image really the better way to do this?

Comment: Depends on what you call better...as I see the perfomance-issue (it surely must be a bug) a big deal, I would say so, yes! If it wasn't for that, the css3 method would defenitely be better.